# Meteor event map working inconsistently

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have been pulling my hair out all weekend trying to work-around little bugs in meteor.  I finally fixed a modal dialog problem, but I still can't figure out why my event map is working inconsistently.

UPDATE: I did figure out the problem.  I had a different js file that also defined editEvent methods, and I guess Meteor doesn't concatenate these methods.  The original problem I posted is still below, just in case you run into a similar issue in your Meteor development.

I am trying to trigger events inside a modal popup: a 'close' and a 'save' button.  I can get the 'close' button to work, but no matter how many different combinations I have tried, I cannot for the life of me understand why the 'save' button won't work, even if I ask it to behave exactly like the close button!

```
Template.editEvent.events({
'click #saveChanges':function(evt,tmpl){
    Session.set('editing_event',null);
    Session.set('showEditEvent',false);
    Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
},

'click #close':function(evt,tmpl){
    Session.set('editing_event',null);
    Session.set('showEditEvent',false);
    Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
}
});
```

And here is my template:

```
<template name="editEvent">
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
    ... some stuff
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" >Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveChanges" >Save changes</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
```

The close event works fine, but the saveChanges event doesn't work at all, even though it is exactly the same!  Does anyone have a clue why this isn't working?

Comment: Is the `</template>` tag only missing above or also in real html?

Comment: I've setup new meteor project and it is working fine.

Comment: haha, the closing `</template>` tag is just missing above, thanks for catching it though!

Comment: @AdamWolski, so you aren't having any issue with this?  OK, maybe I'll try and upgrade my meteor to the latest version and try again